# Date format is not getting displayed

Tags: vb.net

I have referred to solutions provided for date in yyyy-MM-dd format. After providing the format also, I am getting date in default format. Please help.

code:

```
Dim returndate As String
 returndate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
 Dim oDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(returndate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Please provide some form of output or a clearer explanation of the issue you are encountering.

Comment: What is the point of those date-to string-to date gyrations?  `Dim oDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date` will give you the Date portion of today's date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands I'm guessing your output of `oDate` is `27/01/2017 00:00:00`.

What you want to do is this:

```
Dim returndate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
Dim oDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(returndate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Debug.Print(oDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Send the `returndate` into `DateTime.ParseExact` with the format of "dd/MM/yyyy" and then format `oDate` to the desired output, in your case "yyyy-MM-dd".

This is a screenshot of the code and output:

[image]

Dates don't inherently have a format. The format you pass to `ParseExact` is the format it expects of the first parameter, in your case `returndate`. It's not the output format. Have a look over the [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> *format*
>
> A format specifier that defines the required format of s. For more information, see the Remarks section.

Looking at the *Remarks* section:

> The DateTime.ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles) method parses the string representation of a date, which must be in a format defined by the format parameter. It also requires that the date and time elements in s appear in the order specified by format. If s does not match the pattern of the format parameter, with any variations defined by the style parameter, the method throws a FormatException.

Comment: I need answer format in datetype as Date, Your answer is in string

Comment: I need today's date in ÿyyy-MM-dd format but the datatype should be date not string

Comment: As I said in the answer Dates don't have formats. To format you _need_ to use String.  However you can use a Date and then when you want a format send to .ToString(format). @Mugdha

Comment: And you can see from my answer that I do exactly that. I use Date and then when I need format I use .ToString(format).

Comment: @Mugdha do you understand or are you having some difficulty? I can try and explain further if you want. Here the [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) which gives other examples. As you can see the `.ToString` is used for formatting the `Date` for display purpose.

Comment: Thanks!! I have understood and I appreciate your efforts